# PHP dbh prepare statement hang

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

When I run to dbh->prepare , it hangs. What can I do?

```
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'abc-4-sms';
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL payment(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Can you call the procedure okay from your MySQL console? Doesn't that `prepare` need some parameters?

Comment: You can't do prepared statements with `mysql_*`. Where are you getting `$dbh`?

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli/PDO from different codes you found somewhere right ?
Check for a documentation on mysqli_ and stop usqing mysql_

Comment: You cant just copy some part of code from some example and expect to work. Where is your $dbh? Where are values that you bind?

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb' 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL payment(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $something, PDO::PARAM_INT); etc
```

Just search for a PDO tutorial,or better yet read the documentation.